# Dropdownlist Field Form not saved in DB

Tags: forms, model, yii2, dropdown, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new in `Yii2 Framework`. I have a problem, I'm trying to make register form but after register, the role is not saved to database. 
This is the form.

[image: Form visualization]

This is my table for role:

[image: DB-Table]

This is the view code, register.php:

```
<h2>Sign Up : </h2>
                <div class="user-form">
                    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'user_kind')->dropdownList(
                        ArrayHelper::map(CtKindUser::find()->all(), 'id','kindUser'), [
                            'prompt' => 'Choose Category',]); ?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

This is the controller.

```
public function actionRegister()
{
    $model = new User();
    $modelLogin = new LoginForm();

    if($modelLogin->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $modelLogin->login()){
        return $this->goHome();
    }
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->id = $model->generateRandomString();
        $hash = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($model->password);
        $model->password = $hash;
        $model->activated = 1;
        $model->createdAt = date("Y-m-d").' '.date("h:i:s a");
        $model->user_kind = ''; 

        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['/site/index']);

        // return $this->redirect(['/site/index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('register', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelLogin' => $modelLogin,
        ]);
    }
```

And this is the models.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'email', 'password'], 'required'],
            [['activated'], 'integer'],
            [['profile_name'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
            [['id', 'user_kind'], 'string', 'max' => 35],
            [['username', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['createdAt', 'updatedAt'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['user_kind'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['user_kind'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => CtKindUser::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_kind' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'username' => 'Username',
        'profile_name' => '',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'password' => 'Password',
        'category' => 'Category',
        'createdAt' => 'Created At',
        'updatedAt' => 'Updated At',
        'activated' => 'Activated',
        'user_kind' => 'Jenis Pengguna',
        ];
    }

    public function getUserKind()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CtKindUser::className(), ['id' => 'user_kind']);
}
```

Someone, can help me. What is actually the problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: You can write something like this to see what error it returns: `if (!$model->save()) 
{ var_dump($model->errors); }`

Comment: are you saving the form on the first step when you move on to the second step

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam At first, i want to save the data from dropdownlist to database

Answer (score 0):

Check how you are sending your dropdownList:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'user_kind')->dropdownList(['1' =>'Event Organizer', '2' =>'Tenant'],['prompt'=>'Select Category'])?>
```

with the values of `1` and `2` and on your contoller:

```
if ($model->user_kind =='Event Organizer' || $model->user_kind =='Osjfnas8sjaasnaskfowlkvmssjswT' )
```

you are comparing with some values that never will be send `'Event Organizer'` and `'Osjfnas8sjaasnaskfowlkvmssjswT'`

Comment: Ahh.. Okay, I have change the controller and the view anyway.